# Convert MySQL query in to Entity Framework query syntax

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Please can somebody help me convert this MySQL query in to Entity Framework?
Im using that in an ASP .NET project but I only know how to do basic queries in Entity Framework. This seems way too complicated and I cant find a working solution since many hours now...

```
 $rs = mysql_query("SELECT barcode,latitude,longitude,date_time,location_name 
                    FROM sDetails
                    JOIN users on (users.id=sDetails.UserId)  
                    WHERE  (latitude and longitude is not null) 
                       and (latitude <> 100000 and longitude <> 100000)
               and id='$UserId'
            ORDER BY date_time desc");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have generated an Entity Framework model from the database you should be able to do something like (c# example):

```
 var q = context.Details.Where( d => d.UserId = "$UserID" ).
             Where( d => d.latitude.HasValue && d.latitude != 100000 && .. etc ).
             OrderByDescending( d => d.date_time ).
             Select( d => new {d.barcode, d.latitude, d.longitude, etc ... };
```

I'm not sure why you have a join since you're not selecting anything from the **users** tables.

Comment: thanks for the accurate answer. Please look at my answer below. I'm still having some error with that..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Phil
the code you gave above, seems to work mostly, but it still shows an error at
var q = context.**ScanDetails**.Where

> Error 3: 'System.Web.HttpContext' does not contain a definition for
>   'ScanDetails' and no extension method 'ScanDetails' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Web.HttpContext' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

this is the code I have so far:

```
public class read : IHttpHandler
{
    sqlEntities _db = new sqlEntities();

    public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        //Write out the JSON you want to return.

       var q = context.ScanDetails.Where( d => d.UserId = "1" ).
         Where( d => d.latitude.HasValue && d.latitude != 100000  ).
         OrderByDescending( d => d.date_time ).
         Select( d => new {d.barcode, d.latitude, d.longitude };


           // stuff to do here

    }


    public IQueryable<ScanDetail> scanData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: when I put in *context* I meant the database context, in your case *_db*.  Your supposed to amend your question, not add an answer (unless it is an answer of course).

Comment: thanks @Phil 
I accepted your answer as the solution. 
Also I will take in to consideration your suggestion about answering in the future.

Have a great time :)